# Tornado upload error ConnectionResetError

Tags: python, upload, tornado

I have written a test tornado server with upload handler write a file by chunks. Now I try to upload some file to a server through requests library and get a ConnectionResetError, if I make request without a file I don't get this one.

python 3.4, tornado 4.1

server.py:

```python
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, stream_request_body

@stream_request_body
class UploadHandler(RequestHandler):

    def prepare(self):
        self.file = open('uploaded_file', 'wb')

    def data_received(self, chunk):
        print(len(chunk))
        self.file.write(chunk)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.close()
        self.write('UPLOADED')


app = Application([(r'/upload', UploadHandler), ],
                  debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(7777)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Here is what I get:

```python
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.post('http://localhost:7777/upload', files={'file': open('book.pdf', 'rb')})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dim/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dim/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dim/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/dim/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dim/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

>>> resp = requests.post('http://localhost:7777/upload')
>>> resp.status_code
200
```

What do I do wrong? I have read it is the server error. self.prepare() is done, but self.data_received() and post() don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your server logs you should see an uncaught exception from the first line of your `data_received` method. In `@stream_request_body` mode, `self.request.body` is invalid; body data is only available through the `chunk` argument to `data_received`.

When there is an uncaught exception in `data_received`, Tornado closes the connection immediately since most clients will not read an error response until after they have finished uploading the request, so returning an error page is potentially expensive in terms of bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry, i copypasted incorrectly. This line `self.request.body` was odd... Get error anyway

Comment: Ok, i've add `    enable_pretty_logging()` and get `Malformed HTTP message from 127.0.0.1: Content-Length too long`. I should increase max_body_size consiquently

Comment: Yes, `app.listen(7777, max_body_size=150*1024*1024)` and it works =) great. Thx, your `In your server logs ` phrase helped me